# Feature selection on imbalance data

Tags: machine-learning, selection

In my data set the target variable is nominal (there are only two state) and all others are numerical. The data set is highly imbalance. After looking for a solution for handling imbalance data set, I have found SMOTE (Synthetic Minority Over-sampling Technique). The size of the data set increases after applying SMOTE algorithm (I have used Weka implementation of the algorithm).

Now my question is that, how can I determine important features/attributes that affect my target variable most in such a imbalance data set? Is there any implementation available for such algorithm?